# How to get the maximum amount of tuples that are not contained in another set yet?

Tags: python, matching

Given a list of letters, say L=['a','b','c','d','e','f'] and a list of tuples, for example T=[('a','b'),('a','c'),('b','c')].

Now I want to create the maximum amount of possible tuples from the list of L that are not contained in T already. This needs to be done without duplicates, i.e. (a,b) would be the same as (b,a). Also, each letter can only be matched with one other letter.

My idea was:

```
#create a List of all possible tuples first:

all_tuples = [(x,y) for x in L for y in L if x!=y]

#now remove duplicates

unique_tuples = list(set([tuple(sorted(elem)) for elem in all_tuples]))

#Now, create a new set that matches each letter only once with another letter

visited=set()
output = []

for letter1, letter2 in unique tuples:
   if ((letter1, letter2) or (letter2, letter1)) in T:
      continue
   
   if not letter1 in visited and not letter2 in visited:
      visited.add(letter1)
      visited.add(letter2)
      output.append((letter1,letter2))

print(output)
```

However, this does not always give the maximum amount of possible tuples, depending on what T is. For example, let's say we extract the possible unique_tuples=[('a','b'),('a','d'),('b','c')].

If we append ('a','b') first to our output, we cannot append ('b','c') anymore, since 'b' was matched already. However, if we appended ('a','d') first, we could also get ('b','c') afterwards and get the maximum amount of two tuples.

How can one solve this?

Comment: I'm having trouble following the example -- you can't have ('b', 'c') because it's already in T, right?  And how does the "matching with one other letter" work given that T reuses letters?

Comment: Sorry for my confusing writing. I meant that from the set [('a','b'),('a','d'),('b','c')] one could extract at most two tuples such that each letter is matched at most once. However, if one picks ('a','b') first, no other tuple can be chosen.

Comment: And the set T is a given set that does not need to fulfill the rule that letters can only be matched once. That rule only applies to the output.

Answer (score 1):

If we ignore the business about not matching the same letter twice, this is a straightforward use of `combinations`:

```
>>> from itertools import combinations
>>> L=['a','b','c','d','e','f']
>>> T=[('a','b'),('a','c'),('b','c')]
>>> [t for t in combinations(L, 2) if t not in T]
[('a', 'd'), ('a', 'e'), ('a', 'f'), ('b', 'd'), ('b', 'e'), ('b', 'f'), ('c', 'd'), ('c', 'e'), ('c', 'f'), ('d', 'e'), ('d', 'f'), ('e', 'f')]
```

If we limit ourselves to only using each letter once, the problem is very straightforward, because we know that we can only have (letters / 2) tuples at most.  Just find the available letters (by subtracting those already present in T) and then pair them up in any arbitrary order.

```
>>> used_letters = {c for t in T for c in t}
>>> free_letters = [c for c in L if c not in used_letters]
>>> [tuple(free_letters[i:i+2]) for i in range(0, 2 * (len(free_letters) // 2), 2)]
[('d', 'e')]
```

Comment: Thanks, will try it out later!

Comment: This is not exactly what I meant. We can still create tuples that are not contained in T, for example (a,e).

Comment: What you now did is you created a list of tuples that do not contain any letters that appear in T.

Answer (score 0):

Without using libraries, you could do it like this:

```
L=['a','b','c','d','e','f']
T=[('a','b'),('a','c'),('b','c')]

L = sorted(L,key=lambda c: -sum(c in t for t in T))
used = set()
r = [(a,b) for i,a in enumerate(L) for b in L[i+1:]
     if (a,b) not in T and (b,a) not in T
     and used.isdisjoint((a,b)) and not used.update((a,b))]

print(r)
[('a', 'd'), ('b', 'e'), ('c', 'f')]
```

The letters are sorted in descending order of frequency in T before combining them.  This ensures that the hardest letters to match are processed first thus maximizing the pairing potential for the remaining letters.

Alternatively, you could use a recursive (DP) approach and check all possible pairing combinations.

```
def maxTuples(L,T):
    maxCombos = []                          # will return longest
    for i,a in enumerate(L):                # first letter of tuple
        for j,b in enumerate(L[i+1:],i+1):  # second letter of tuple
            if (a,b) in T: continue         # tuple not in T
            if (b,a) in T: continue         # inverted tuple not in T
            rest = L[:i]+L[i+1:j]+L[j+1:]   # recurse with rest of letters
            R = [(a,b)]+maxTuples(rest,T)   # adding to selected pair
            if len(R)*2+1>=len(L): return R # max possible, stop here
            if len(R)>len(maxCombos):       # longer combination of tuples
                maxCombos = R               # Track it
    return maxCombos
```

...

```
L=['a','b','c','d','e','f']
T=[('a','b'),('a','c'),('b','c'),('c','f')]

print(maxTuples(L,T))        

[('a', 'd'), ('b', 'f'), ('c', 'e')]


L = list("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP")
T = [('K', 'N'), ('G', 'F'), ('I', 'P'), ('C', 'A'), ('O', 'M'), 
     ('D', 'B'), ('L', 'J'), ('E', 'H'), ('F', 'E'), ('L', 'H'), 
     ('J', 'G'), ('N', 'I'), ('C', 'M'), ('A', 'P'), ('D', 'O'), 
     ('K', 'B'), ('G', 'H'), ('O', 'A'), ('I', 'J'), ('N', 'M'), 
     ('F', 'P'), ('E', 'B'), ('K', 'L'), ('D', 'C'), ('D', 'E'), 
     ('L', 'F'), ('B', 'H'), ('I', 'A'), ('K', 'G'), ('M', 'O'), 
     ('P', 'C'), ('N', 'J'), ('J', 'E'), ('N', 'P'), ('A', 'G'), 
     ('H', 'O'), ('I', 'B'), ('K', 'F'), ('M', 'C'), ('L', 'D'), 
     ('A', 'B'), ('C', 'E'), ('D', 'F'), ('G', 'I'), ('H', 'J'), 
     ('K', 'M'), ('L', 'N'), ('O', 'P')]

print(maxTuples(L,T))        

[('A', 'D'), ('B', 'C'), ('E', 'G'), ('F', 'H'), 
 ('I', 'K'), ('J', 'M'), ('L', 'P'), ('N', 'O')]
```

*Note that the function will be slow if the tuples in T exclude so many pairings that it is impossible to produce a combination of len(L)/2 tuples.  It can be optimized further by filtering letters that are completely excluded as we go down the recursion:*

```
def maxTuples(L,T):
    if not isinstance(T,dict):        
        T,E = {c:{c} for c in L},T               # convert T to a dictionary
        for a,b in E: T[a].add(b);T[b].add(a)    # of excluded letter sets
    L = [c for c in L if not T[c].issuperset(L)] # filter fully excluded   
    maxCombos = []                          # will return longest
    for i,a in enumerate(L):                # first letter of tuple
        for j,b in enumerate(L[i+1:],i+1):  # second letter of tuple
            if b in T[a]: continue          # exclude tuples in T
            rest = L[:i]+L[i+1:j]+L[j+1:]   # recurse with rest of letters
            R = [(a,b)]+maxTuples(rest,T)   # adding to selected pair
            if len(R)*2+1>=len(L): return R # max possible, stop here
            if len(R)>len(maxCombos):       # longer combination of tuples
                maxCombos = R               # Track it
    return maxCombos
```

Comment: Thanks! I also had that approach using the library collections.Counter. However, as you stated, it only increases likelihood and does not guarantee the maximum number of tuples.

Comment: Still, what does "and not used.update((a,b))" exactly do? THanks

Comment: `and not used.update((a,b))` adds letters in `a` and `b` to the `used` set so that these letters are not used again in for the remaining tuples.

Comment: I will try on the data that did not work out for me with my approach tomorrow and let you know!

Comment: It doesn't work properly. Take for example:

Comment: T=[('K', 'N'), ('G', 'F'), ('I', 'P'), ('C', 'A'), ('O', 'M'), ('D', 'B'), ('L', 'J'), ('E', 'H'), ('F', 'E'), ('L', 'H'), ('J', 'G'), ('N', 'I'), ('C', 'M'), ('A', 'P'), ('D', 'O'), ('K', 'B'), ('G', 'H'), ('O', 'A'), ('I', 'J'), ('N', 'M'), ('F', 'P'), ('E', 'B'), ('K', 'L'), ('D', 'C'), ('D', 'E'), ('L', 'F'), ('B', 'H'), ('I', 'A'), ('K', 'G'), ('M', 'O'), ('P', 'C'), ('N', 'J'), ('J', 'E'), ('N', 'P'), ('A', 'G'), ('H', 'O'), ('I', 'B'), ('K', 'F'), ('M', 'C'), ('L', 'D'), ('A', 'B'), ('C', 'E'), ('D', 'F'), ('G', 'I'), ('H', 'J'), ('K', 'M'), ('L', 'N'), ('O', 'P')]

Comment: L = list of all aplhabetical letters form 'A' to 'P'

Comment: Your first code would give r= [('A', 'D'), ('B', 'C'), ('E', 'G'), ('F', 'H'), ('I', 'K'), ('J', 'M'), ('L', 'O')], which contains only 7 tuples instead of the maximum number of 8

Comment: However, one could do better with the combination [('A', 'E'), ('B', 'F'), ('C', 'G'), ('D', 'H'), ('I', 'L'), ('J', 'K'), ('M', 'P'), ('O', 'N')] for example

Comment: I see. So the first solution does leave out some possibilities.  BTW I optimized the recursive function so that it will respond much faster with the larger lists. (and it does produce a combination of 8 tuples)

Comment: Thanks, will check it out tomorrow and let you know if it worked for me! Thanks for your effort